# Query string of Webclient to json string - c#

Tags: c#, json, query-string

I'm using below query for sending data to webAPI. It is working fine. How can I convert the query string that I used , into a json string within this function? Is it possible?

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        wc.QueryString.Add("unique_id", (checklist_ID.ToString()));
        wc.QueryString.Add("Question_no", (QNO.ToString()));
        wc.QueryString.Add("Question", t1_question.Text.ToString());
        wc.QueryString.Add("Password", t1_password.Text.ToString());

        var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);

         //here I want this Querystring data in below json format 
         // [{"unique_id":"2233","Question_no":"43","Question":"XXXX??","Password":"testpswd"}]

        var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: sending JSON on the querystring of the URL doesn't make much sense. Either send querystring values separately _or_ send JSON in the body of the request. (Or you can in fact send url-encoded values (i.e. they look like a querystring) in the body of the request, too.). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723705/set-a-body-for-webclient-when-making-a-post-request if you want to know how to set the content of the request body using WebClient.

Comment: this is for log the data in a text file that I send to webapi

Comment: Ok. And your point is? How does that relate to what you've asked, or what I've just told you?

Comment: I'm trying to get this array [{"unique_id":"2233","Question_no":"43","Question":"XXXX??"}] from QueryString I used to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Linq` and `JsonConvert` to get the desired result

```
//Use LINQ to convert the QueryString to Dictionary
var keyValuePairs = (
        from key in wc.QueryString.AllKeys
        from value in wc.QueryString.GetValues(key)
        select new { key, value }).ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);

//Use Newtonsoft.Json to Serialize the object to json format
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyValuePairs));
```

Comment: is there any way to hide the password key as "*****" in this keyValuePairs? for ex: [{"unique_id":"2233","Question_no":"43","Question":"XXXX??","Password":"******"}]

Comment: ```keyValuePairs.FirstOrDefault (kvp=>kvp.Key.Equals ("Password"))?.Value = "******"```